# how we can correct pattern for digits only

Tags: html, validation

In this field we can enter only digits

my code is

```
<input name="issue_bal" id="issue_bal" 
 type="text" required="required" 
 pattern="[0-9]" tabindex="1" 
 class="limiter mid"/>
```

but this is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern only describes **1** digit, not multiple. In order to validate 1 or more digits use the following pattern:

```
pattern="[0-9]+"
```

Comment: Better than mine, will delete it :)

Comment: Thanks Exelian for help