# how i can enter digit in text input field without pattern in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying with pattern but it is not working on my theme. Now i think its good to work in javascript or jquery.

```
 <input name="abc" id="abc" type="text" required="required" tabindex="1"/>
```

what is the javascript or jquery code for numeric value (not in negative)

Comment: Am asking With js and jQuery

Comment: what do you actually want to do?

Comment: Just like @user1671639 I also didnt get your question either.

Comment: `document.getElementById('abc').value = 10` or `$('#abc').val('10')`

Comment: Keep using the same question to get the result you need. You don't have to create a new one every time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811178/how-we-can-correct-pattern-for-digits-only

Comment: I want js or jQuery script which valid for numeric values

Comment: Use input type = number HTML5 control and there you have pattern=/[0-9]/ and min=0

Comment: sudhAnsu63, pattern is not working in my theme

Comment: @FelipeMiosso I Know but pattern is not working in my theme thats why i create new one

Comment: @NavjotSingh It wont work with **type="text"** change to *type="number"*

Answer (score 3):

Try HTML 5 control. You will get all this.

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5" pattern=/[0-9]/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all you can do with javascript.

```
   var val=document.getElementById('abc').value;

    if(isNaN(val)){
       alert('This is not a Number');
    }else if(val< 0){
        alert('This is a negative Number');
    }else{
       alert('This is a Number');
    }
```

you can also use HTML5 dom like

```
<input type="number" min="0" />
```